# Does "up" mean "upstairs" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I read this sentence:

> She brought the rainbow socks up to her room.

Does "up" mean "upstairs" here? Perhaps in this short story for children, the writer is saving words. Or does it mean something else?

Comment: It almost certainly implies 'up[stairs] to her [bed]room'. Most readers would understand it that way, so there is no need to spell it out.

Comment: It's not down to the basement, is it?